# How to prevent Multi Dex in Android

Tags: android, aar, android-multidex

We have developed an android library (`aar`) using Java and it depends on android support library v4. In fact, we have extended `ViewPager` (`android.support.v4.view.ViewPager`) class and consumed it in our library’s GUI.

We have applied proguard on the library and it works fine with our test apps but we have a customer that has developed its android app in native C++ and they are going to integrate our component into their app and there is an issue on build.

They receive `com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException` on build which is a sign of having more than almost 64K methods that are allowed in a single `dex`.

They asked us to use fewer or smaller dependencies as they have to include our component dependencies into their build setting and one of their suggestions is that we should extract `ViewPager` out of android support source and put it in our component source code.

Now the questions are

1. If we extract `ViewPager` out of android source and add it to our
   library source code then will it reduce the amount of methods to
   prevent mentioned exception? Is it a good practice to do that?
2. What is the best way to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> If we extract ViewPager out of android source and add it to our library source code then will it reduce the amount of methods to prevent mentioned exception?

Probably not, at least for `release` builds. Your customer should have configured ProGuard, which will identify and remove unnecessary code pulled in via libraries.

> Is it a good practice to do that?

No. Your customer should know better than that.

> What is the best way to resolve this issue?

Mostly, it is not your problem. It is your customer's problem. Your customer is blaming you, but there is no evidence in your question that your library is a significant source of the customer's DEX method references.

Your customer should be configuring ProGuard, and your customer should use the APK Analyzer in Android Studio 2.2+ to see where their method references come from.

You, in your library, could:

- Try to use more focused dependencies than `support-v4`. `ViewPager` itself is in the `support-core-ui` artifact. However, if you are using `FragmentPagerAdapter` or `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, in addition you will need either `support-fragment` (if you are using the `v4` edition of those classes) or `support-v13` (if you are using the `v13` edition of those classes).
- Use the APK Analyzer on some demo project that you create that uses your library, so you can see how many DEX method references that your library uses, to see if you are really a significant source of such references.
- Suggest ProGuard settings for your customer that will keep required classes of yours, to help them use ProGuard effectively with their app.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `jumboMode` in your `build.gradle`file like this:

```
dexOptions {
    jumboMode true
}
```

This option will allow you to have 32it wide string references in your `.dex` file. Thus you can have 2^32 referenced strings in your project.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Available options are :

1. Yes, you can extract `ViewPager` from support library. `ViewPager` import some files from support library that are also required to be extracted. This will reduce method count with significant difference.
2. You can also use `exclude` parameter in dependencies in `build.gradle` file.

```
    compile ('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
```